# Why am I getting freeze error when I create a new object with ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

Even when I make a copy of the object passed as a parameter in an action payload I'm still getting this error.

Here is the reducer:

```
case '[Modal] Open modal with message':
            return {
                ...state,
                isVisible: true,
                modal: {
                    header: actions.payload.header,
                    message: actions.payload.message,
                    messages: actions.payload.messages,
                    buttons: actions.payload.buttons ? actions.payload.buttons : [],
                    onDismissAction: actions.payload.onDismissAction ? actions.payload.onDismissAction : null
                }
            };
```

And here is the way I call it:

```
deleteRequestedDay(vacation: Vacation): void {
    const vv = {...vacation};
    
    this.store.dispatch(ModalActions.OpenModal({
      header: 'Delete vacation',
      message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this vacation?',
      buttons: [
        {
          action: VacationsActions.DeleteVacation({ vacation: vv }),
          text: 'Yes'
        }
      ]
    }));
  }
```

If I create a new Vacation object it works fine. If I use vacation function parameter directly it crashes with the cannot freeze error.

But with object spread operator {...vacation} I get the cannot freeze error too.

The solution I've found is to create a new Vacation object with the relevant parameters but I think it is an unnecesary step.

The error:

[image]

Comment: What is `VacationsActions.DeleteVacation` ? It looks like you're sending a ngrx action in the payload ?

Comment: Hello Jean-Xavier, thanks a lot for answer. Yes, it is an action I send to another component. This other component can dispatch this action or not. I think an action as an object with no effect until it is dispatched. This action will be dispatched if a button is pressed in a modal.